# "You did the right thing" Is this sentence idiomatic in English?

Tags: word-usage

My sister married a man who treated her badly. Her husband didn't respect her at all. After one year , they split up. After hearing that news , I called my sister and said :

Don't worry. I think you'll marry the man who deserves you. I strongly believe that ***you did the right thing.***

Is this sentence idiomatic in English?

Thank you.

Comment: If she initiated the split, then it is. A cursory search for the term should give you many examples, in similar circumstances.

Comment: Yes, my sister initiated the split.

Comment: @JHCL What does initiation of the split have to do with "you did the right thing"? She might have accepted what hur husband initiated.

Comment: Drop the unnecessary "that" which precedes "you," and the sentence looks fine. Is it idiomatic? No. Don

Comment: Spike Lee even made [a movie using it for the title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_the_Right_Thing). Although it's hard to see this as "idomatic" since it is a literal expression.

Comment: I'm so sorry.I'm a little confused. @rhetorician said it's fine and then he said Is it idiomatic? no. is this sentence correct in this context or not?

Comment: He wanted to mean that it is "correct" even though it is not idiomatic. Don't worry and you can use it.

Comment: Perfectly idiomatic as it stands.  Of course there are about 50 ways it could be reworded, and everyone here will have their own favorite, but you have no need to second-guess yourself on this one.

Comment: @Rathony - To clarify, you're right. If she had the opportunity to fight or challenge the break-up and did not do so, then the expression is just as appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this sentence is correct, and it is idiomatic:

> **do the right thing**
>
> **To act or behave correctly, appropriately**, or with the best intentions.

(http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/do+the+right+thing)

You could've said, "What you did was appropriate, your actions were correct". Instead, you used a natural English idiom to get the same message across.

Note the the word "idiom" has several meanings (it's a polysemic word). Consider:

> Meaning 1: a manner of speaking that is natural to native speakers of a language
>
> Meaning 4: an expression whose meanings cannot be inferred from the meanings of the words that make it up

([Princeton WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=IDIOM))

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: Just a slight addition to your fine answer. "Do the right thing" may in fact be somewhat idiomatic, but not as clearly as, say, "Jim is a stand-up guy," which would be difficult to interpret for a person whose first language is not English. That's all. Don

Comment: @rhetorician Thank you for your comment. I agree that *do the right thing* is an order of magnitude more understandable to a non-native speaker than, say, "under the weather" or "kick the bucket". But it's idiomatic in the sense of being part of natural parlance. Perhaps that's the reason thefreedictionary.com places it under Idioms.